# How to send form data into isset function using js

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

how to submit the form in multistep form and insert into DB

I have made a form like a multi-step previous next button also made using js. now I want to submit the form and send to the database in php

**FORM HTML:**

```
<form action="method.php" method="post" name="htlregistration_F" id="htlregistration_F" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <section id="form_part1" class="tab" >
        <h3  class="bodytext bodyheading " ><strong>Applicant Details</strong></h3>
        <label class="bodytext">Applicant First Name<span class="redtext"> *</span>
            <input name="appfirstname_f"  type="text" id="appfirstname_f" class="input form-control" maxlength="25" required>&nbsp;
            <span class="redtext" id="errorFirst" >(Max length 25 chars)</span>
        </label>
    </section>
    <section id="form_part4" class="tab " >
        <h3  class="bodytext bodyheading " ><strong>Contact Details</strong></h3>
        <label class="bodytext" >Phone (Mobile)<span class="redtext" id="errorMobile"> *</span>
            <input name="phmob_f" type="text" id="phmob_f"  class="input form-control" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required="">&nbsp;
            <span class="redtext">(Max length 10 chars)</span>
        </label>
    </section>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">&laquo; Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" name="licensesubmit" onclick="nextPrev(1)">&raquo; Next </button>
        </div>
    </div>        
</form>
```

**MY PAGE SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab


    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";  
            // What should do after this step to connect to isset function?  
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
    }
</script>


<?php

    // I want to reach here after form submission
    if (isset($_POST["licensesubmit"])) 
    { 
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, TRUE) . '</pre>';
        die();         

?>
```

Comment: You could simply add a `submit` input button at the bottom of the form but if you need to use Javascript you can send the data in an ajax request - using a FormData object would be simplest perhaps. In your `showTab` function you probably wish to change the button type so that it can actually submit the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the javascript `showTab` function is the same but I modified to use classnames. When you reach the condition `n == ( tabs.length - 1 )` change the `type` of the button from a regular `button` to `submit`  -if the condition changes by the user going backwards then change the button back again to a regular button.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* to emulate `method.php` ... process FORM submission... */
        
        
        if( isset( $_POST['licensesubmit'] ) ){
            $_POST['banana']='curvy yellow fruit';  #this will only be visible IF isset( $_POST['licensesubmit'] ) is TRUE
        }
        
        
        exit( sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($_POST,true) ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Multi-stage form</title>
        <style>
            body *{font-family:monospace;box-sizing:border-box;}
            section{border:1px solid gray;margin:1rem;width:calc( 100% - calc( 4rem + 2px ) );padding:1rem }
            .tab{display:none;}
            .visible{display:block;}
            .stage1{background:whitesmoke;}
            .stage2{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.1);}
            .stage3{background:rgba(0,0,255,0.1);}
            .stage4{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);}
        </style>
        <script>

            function showTab(n) {
                let prev=document.getElementById('prevBtn');
                let next=document.getElementById('nextBtn');
                
                let tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
                    Array.from( tabs ).forEach( tab=>{
                        if( tab.classList.contains('visible') )tab.classList.remove('visible');
                    })
                    tabs[ n ].classList.add('visible');
                    
                    
                prev.style.display=( n==0 ) ? 'none' : 'inline';

                
                if( n == ( tabs.length - 1 ) ) {
                    next.innerHTML = 'Submit';
                    next.type='submit';
                } else {
                    next.innerHTML = 'Next';
                    next.type='button'
                }
            };
            function nextPrev(i){
                currentTab=currentTab + i;
                showTab( currentTab );
            };
            
            let currentTab=0;
            
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                showTab( currentTab );              
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' name='htlregistration_F'><!-- removed action so that this form POSTS to the same page for demonstration -->
        
            <section id='form_part1' class='tab stage1'>
                <h3  class='bodytext bodyheading ' ><strong>Applicant Details</strong></h3>
                <label class='bodytext'>Applicant First Name<span class='redtext'> *</span>
                    <input name='appfirstname_f'  type='text' class='input form-control' maxlength='25' required />&nbsp;
                    <span class='redtext' id='errorFirst' >(Max length 25 chars)</span>
                </label>
            </section>
            
            <section id='form_part2' class='tab stage2'>
                <h3  class='bodytext bodyheading ' ><strong>Applicant Juggling ability</strong></h3>
                <label class='bodytext'>Can you juggle hedgehogs?<span class='redtext'> *</span>
                    <input name='appjuggle'  type='text' class='input form-control' maxlength='25' required />&nbsp;
                    <span class='redtext' >(Max length 25 chars)</span>
                </label>
            </section>
            
            <section id='form_part3' class='tab stage3'>
                <h3  class='bodytext bodyheading ' ><strong>Applicant ESP Level</strong></h3>
                <label class='bodytext'>ESP ability<span class='redtext'> *</span>
                    <input name='appesp'  type='text' class='input form-control' maxlength='25' required />&nbsp;
                    <span class='redtext' >(Max length 25 chars)</span>
                </label>
            </section>
            
            <section id='form_part4' class='tab stage4'>
                <h3  class='bodytext bodyheading ' ><strong>Contact Details</strong></h3>
                <label class='bodytext' >Phone (Mobile)<span class='redtext' id='errorMobile'> *</span>
                    <input name='phmob_f' type='text' class='input form-control' minlength='10' maxlength='10' required />&nbsp;
                    <span class='redtext'>(Max length 10 chars)</span>
                </label>
            </section>
            
            
            
            
            <div style='overflow:auto;'>
                <div style='float:right;'>
                    <button type='button' id='prevBtn' onclick='nextPrev(-1)'>&laquo; Previous</button>
                    <button type='button' id='nextBtn' name='licensesubmit' onclick='nextPrev(1)'>&raquo; Next </button>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Output similar to:

```
Array
(
    [appfirstname_f] => geronimo
    [appjuggle] => fluently
    [appesp] => none
    [phmob_f] => 0141 353 3
    [licensesubmit] => 
    [banana] => curvy yellow fruit
)
```

Comment: Thanks sir very precise answer it works with my code

Comment: I'm glad I was able to offer some assistance to you! Good luck with the remaining coding adventures